# When reversing an array i get the following error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int’ and ‘int *’)

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors

I am reversing an array using pointers :

```
void reverse(int *a,int n){
int i = 0,j = n-1;
while(i < j){
    int tmp;
    tmp = *(a+i);
    *(a+i) = *(a+j)
    *(a+j) = tmp;
    i++;
    j--;
}
```

}
    The error i get :

```
error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int’ and ‘int *’)
     *(a+i) = *(a+j)
              ~~~~~~
     *(a+j) = tmp;
     ^~~~~~
```

I am very confused about why this happens.

Comment: You have a missing `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only problem is missing  `;` here `*(a+i) = *(a+j)`.

Comment: Oh, good. I already started to doubt my understanding of pointers